# If/Else Statements In Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I'm trying to create an RPG game in Batch/CMD. I want to make it so that when the user enters a number that isn't one of the ones listed it just reloads from the last marker. Here is the code:

```
if %1st%==1 %atk%+25 
if %1st%==2 %def%+25 
if %1st%==3 %hp%+25 
if %1st%==4 %iq%+25 
if %1st%==5 %luck%+25 

if not %1st%==1 goto 1st
if not %1st%==2 goto 1st
if not %1st%==3 goto 1st
if not %1st%==4 goto 1st
if not %1st%==5 goto 1st
```

Comment: OK. What is or isn't working?

Comment: It keeps crashing the program instead of going back to the last marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice not to have you variables start with a number, as `%1` means the first parameter passed into the script.  If you didn't pass any parameters to the script, the interpreter is seeing these statements as `if not st%==1 goto 1st` and `if st%==1 %atk%+25` which are not valid.

You need to replace all `%1st%` with a proposed `%first%` and the rest as follows:
`%2nd%` to `%second%`
`%3rd%` to `%third%`
`%4th%` to `%fourth%`
`%5th%` to `%fifth%`
`%6th%` to `%sixth%`
`%7th%` to `%seventh%`
`%8th%` to `%eighth%`
`%9th%` to `%ninth%`

Here is you code with the changes mentioned above:

```
if %first%==1 %atk%+25 
if %first%==2 %def%+25 
if %first%==3 %hp%+25 
if %first%==4 %iq%+25 
if %first%==5 %luck%+25 

if not %first%==1 goto first
if not %first%==2 goto first
if not %first%==3 goto first
if not %first%==4 goto first
if not %first%==5 goto first
```

And I'm not sure how you're adding the values, here is a proposed changes with `set /a` commands:

```
if %first%==1 set /a atk=%atk%+25 
if %first%==2 set /a def=%def%+25 
if %first%==3 set /a hp=%hp%+25 
if %first%==4 set /a iq=%iq%+25 
if %first%==5 set /a luck=%luck%+25 

if not %first%==1 goto first
if not %first%==2 goto first
if not %first%==3 goto first
if not %first%==4 goto first
if not %first%==5 goto first
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will remember not to use values with numbers in them!